# How can I avoid Type Mismatch using the Split function in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, split

I'm getting a run time error 13 (Type Mismatch) when trying to use the Split function in Excel VBA. I've read a number of articles on it, but even when I use the example from the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) I get the same error. Here's the boiled-down code I'm trying to make work:

```
Sub SplitTest2()

Dim strSliceMe As String
Dim arrSliced() As Variant

strSliceMe = Range("A1").Value ' Cell A1 contains "Hello, world!"
arrSliced() = Split(strSliceMe, ", ")

Debug.Print arrSliced(1)

End Sub
```

When I run this, I'm hit with a type mismatch. Upon debugging, it takes me to this line:

```
arrSliced() = Split(strSliceMe, ", ")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Dim arrSliced() As String`

Comment: Or `Dim arrSliced As Variant`, `arrSliced = Split(strSliceMe, ", ")`.

Comment: Side note: MS documentation unfortunately has errors ... the snippet from the docs is wrong.

Comment: Both responses appear to solve it for me. Thanks much for your assistance!

Comment: +1 regarding the errors in MS documentation. I had noticed a few things that didn't look right in that post, but I was hoping that the basic gist would be correct. oops.